# Flash SWF Alternative Save methods for Role Play Game

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I am looking for alternative save game methods, these include that if a person stores his data or saves it, it cannot be deleted, even when he clears his/her cache+cookies. Can anyone tell me some ways to load and save a users data; that cannot be deleted even when he or she clears there cache+cookies. Looking forward for answers in ActionScript 2 only.

Comment: If you're new to Flash you should start with current ActionScript 3 which also introduces hardware accelerated Stage3D capabilities easily leveraged for game development.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store it locally to the machine, I think [SharedObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=Part2_AS2_LangRef_1.html) will come closest to what you want. Otherwise, you'll want to [connect to a server](http://search.atomz.com/search/?sp-p=any&sp-f=iso-8859-1&sp-g=2&sp-a=sp040c2f00&sp-q=php%20mysql) and store the information there.